# How do I access internal objects from hosted IronPython?

Tags: .net, ironpython

I'm hosting IronPython 2.0 in a C#/Winforms application.  I would like Python to be able to access various global, static objects in the host application.

As an example, the host application has an internal static class 'Global', which contains a number of static public members, which are are the various global objects I'd like to access:

```
static class Global
{
  public static FeederSystem Feed ...
  public static LightingSystem Lighting ...
  public static IOSystem Io ...
  ... etc
}
```

I want to be able to refer to Global.Lighting.xxx in Python code, just as I can in the C# application.

Is there an IronPythonic equivalent of 'InternalsVisibleTo' which I can use to allow Python code to see the internal types of the host application?  Or do I need to make them all public?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so I worked this out myself, with the aid of the DLR spec, from here https://github.com/IronLanguages/dlr/blob/master/Docs/dlr-spec-hosting.pdf and by looking at the IP/DLR source.

This isn't very elegant, and using a ScriptRuntimeSetup object with the PrivateBinding property set True would probably be a neater route than using CreateEngine.

But this one works:

```
Dictionary<string, object> options = new Dictionary<string, object>();
options.Add("PrivateBinding", true);

_engine = Python.CreateEngine(options);
```

Comment: Note: check https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython2/blob/master/Src/IronPython/Runtime/Types/PythonTypeInfo.cs#L501: class members (properties/methds/....) which are internal are also exposed but not by their original name, instead by _<type>__<member> so suppose `Feed` in the example code above wasn't public, it would be accessed in Python by `Global._Global__Feed`.